# QuerySelector in Puppeteer doesn't find element (returns null)

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm trying to access elements on a website with Puppeteer. Following is my minimal working example. The output of the `page.evaluate` is `null` when I try to get the `span` element. When I change it to the `p` element it correctly outputs an emtpy object. Is this because the `span` element has `display: none` ? What do I have to do to get the span element?

```
(async() => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
        timeout: 1000
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://example.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});

    const elem = await page.evaluate(() => {

        const elem = document.querySelector('span');
        return elem;

    })

    console.log("ELEM", elem)
    browser.close();

})();
```

Comment: There is no `span` but two `p` on that URL. All the reason there is.

Comment: Hmm weird. In the chrome developer console, I can see a span with display: none. When I do view source there is no such span however and neither is there one when I open the firefox developer tools. This is confusing!

Comment: Oh no! I just realized that this span is being added by an extension.

Answer (score -1):

An additional [`span`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) element was being added by an extension to the Page DOM, which resulted in the incorrect selector specified for [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

The correct selector, based on the information given, is `'p'`:

```
const elem = document.querySelector('p');
```